# Capturing serial welcome message when connecting in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a program that communicates with a controller.  The controller is supposed to send a "welcome" message when a connection is successfully established and, in fact, it does when I connect using a communications software.  However, using the .NET code below, I never see the welcome message.  Beyond that, it works.  How can I capture this message.  It seems to be sent the moment the connection is established.

Again, I am able to communicate fine with the controller after connection but I simply cannot seem to get the welcome message that is sent a the moment the connection is opened.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String myString);
        public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;
        SerialPort sp;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddDataMethod(String myString)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(myString);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                sp = new SerialPort(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),Int32.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));
                sp.DataReceived += SerialPort_OnDataReceived;
                sp.Close();
                sp.Open();
                richTextBox1.AppendText("open\n");
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        void SerialPort_OnDataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            SerialPort sp = sender as SerialPort;            
            string s = sp.ReadExisting();
            richTextBox1.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] { s });
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }    

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
            sp.DiscardInBuffer();
            sp.Close();
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\nclosed\n");

        }
        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);
            string[] Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.Items.Count - 1;
            Array.Sort(Ports, (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Substring(3).PadLeft(3, '0'), b.Substring(3).PadLeft(3, '0')));
            foreach (string port in Ports)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does breakpoint in `DataRecevied` ever hit? You are setting too little of `SerialPort` configuration properties, check baud rate, bit size, handshake, etc. Maybe your controller receives nothing.

Comment: Serial ports sit at the very bottom of the OSI network layer model.  They don't know beans about "connections", it requires the kind of protocol that TCP uses.  You in general have to tickle the controller with *something*, tends to be as simple as sending a single "\r" or "\n".  Long odds for it seeing your RTS or DTR handshake signal turn on after a power-up.  Check the manual or use a telephone.  Or you just plain don't receive anything at all, a likely outcome when you ignore the Handshake property.

Comment: Sinatr, I am able to communicate with the controller fine when I connect. I can send commands to it (via textBox1) and receive responses without a hitch.  The only problem is that I am unable to get the initial welcome message.  This message essentially contains the version number of the controller which I would like to capture.  The other parameters for 'serial' are fine.  In reality this is a USB device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.  Required a slight delay between connection and trying to pull data from the port.